# How to use a gradient in Native Base's Box in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, native-base

I'm trying to use Native Base in a browser ReactJS application (not a React Native one), and I'm struggling to use gradient background for Box in this case.

The [documentation](https://docs.nativebase.io/box#h3-with-linear-gradient) only explains how to do it on React Native environment (Expo or vanilla React Native), but nothing about ReactJS applications.

It seems not possible to "inject" some class names to `div`s at some point with Native Base, so not possible to create the gradient in pure CSS aside of Native Base.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be able to use the "With Ref" example at the bottom of the documentation to get a gradient.

I was able to use arbitrary CSS in the "styleObj" example, and was able to create a gradient:

[image: screenshot of Native Base playground demonstrating gradient background]